# Android Development: How To Keep Text When Orientation Changes?

Tags: android, text, orientation, textview

In my app I have a TextView that I use setText on after a certain action.
But when the orientation changes the TextView's text is changed back to normal.

I have a similar problem with my app's file browser, for some reason it goes back to /sdcard/ when the orientation changes :/

Is there anything I can do to prevent loosing the TextView's text?

Comment: Are you handling the "orientation" configuration change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store all your view's contents in `onSaveInstanceState()` and reload it in `onCreate()`. If you want to be funny and have all those values persist even after a system reboot, you could use `SharedPreferences`, but saving the instance state is probably what you want here.